# Display text in a statusbar for android

Tags: delphi

It seems the status bar in android has no text property. I am trying to display
uniconnection username there with no luck.

How do you manipulate the statusbar so it displays text ?

Comment: If you're talking about FMX then [example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_Hints_to_Show_Contextual_Help_in_a_FireMonkey_Application#Status_Bar) and [demo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FMX.ControlsDemo_Sample#Classes) imply you put children controls into the StatusBar and operate on those.

Comment: @AmigoJack: If the OP is talking about Delphi and Android, they have to be talking about FMX. VCL doesn't work on platforms other than Windows.

Comment: so the statusbar is practically useless... :(

Comment: @user763539 why do you say that? What is stopping you from "*putting children controls into the StatusBar*" as needed?